# Instagram ios: open link in safari - universal link code

Tags: javascript, ios, instagram

Is there any working solution in 2020 to force instagram to open a link in mobile safari instead of webview? Inside I can't use mobile camera which is quite crucial.

Other apps have there universal link codes which force browsers to open them (ie. Facebook has fb://). Does safari have its own code? Went through the whole internet and there is no mention of it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, 
Instagram or Facebook blocks any

```
window.open(link, ...)
```

I tried using

> user agent

Parsing

Example is here: https://jsfiddle.net/jfqba6ut/9/show